# Why is my Angular Async/Await loop exiting before it execute for each index?

Tags: angular, typescript, loops, for-loop, async-await

I have an asnyc function in Angular that is exiting before it finishing all of its await calls in a loop.

It only runs 1 await call currently. Any ideas?

```js
  async rtClick() {
    for (let index = 0; index < this.mulObj.value.length; index++) {
      const selectedRT = this.mulObj.value[index];
      await this.runRTSub(selectedRT);
      console.log(index);
    }
    console.log('spot 2')

  }
```

In the example above even when there are 5 objects in the array I will console log "spot 2" right after the first await completes. I am expecting all 5 awaits to loop and complete before "spot 2" appears.

Below is what runRTSub calls.

```js
  runRTSub(selectedRT) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.DbService.getRTSP(selectedRT).subscribe(rtsp_results => this.rtsp_results = rtsp_results,
      (err) => {
         console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(err)); 
    },() => {
      resolve(1);
    });
  });
  }
```

Comment: @NicholasTower -- I added this detail. Is my issue due to the promise? Sorry if stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

## Awaiting Promises

You must mark your promise callback `async` for it to be awaitable.

Here is a simple example using setTimeout() to illustrate:

```js
// returns 'done' after 500ms
function mockPromise() {
    /* NOTE: the promise callback has been marked async because we expect to await it later */
    return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res("done"), 500)
  });
}

async function testMockPromise() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(await mockPromise());
  }
  console.log("final")
}
testMockPromise();
  /* outputs:
    done
    done
    done
    done
    done
    final /*
```

Comment: I added async and it still only runs 1 iteration of the loop versus the 5 expected. I set my loop to console.log the index and I set a console.log of "spot 2" for after the for loop is complete inside rtClick and my log looks like this:

0
spot 2

So it runs index 0 and then its done. Does it have anything to do with the fact that mine don't start with async function? Or that I am subscribing?